# TeradataSQL: How to Standardize Times that are in Both 24 and 12 Hour Format

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm using a database which is a complete mess and need to figure out the best way to fix it. Right now I have times that are coming into this table that are in 12 hour and 24 hour format (some are 01:30 PM and some are 13:30 PM). To properly compare the scheduled times to the actual times I need them in a standardized 24 hour format.

Example Table Below: 
*Note* I can not do any permanent changes as I don't have those privileges with this data.

```
Sched St Date         Sched Time  Actual Start            Actual End
09/11/2017 00:00:00   11:30 AM    09/11/2017 11:34:16     09/11/2017 11:58:00
05/26/2017 00:00:00   03:30 PM    05/26/2017 15:40:00     05/26/2017 15:55:15
11/06/2017 00:00:00   19:30 PM    11/06/2017 21:25:00     11/06/2017 21:45:00
```

Right now I have:

```
    Select DB.TBL.*, 
    case when left (Sched_Time, 2) > 12
    and Sched_Time like '%PM%' 
    then concat((left(Sched_Time, 2) - 12),right(Sched_Time, 6))
Else concat(Left(Sched_Time,2)right(Sched_Time, 6)) 
End;
```

I'm getting an error when I try to concat to get the full time (i.e. 07:00 PM). Can anyone help me out with a clean way to do this?

Comment: I can't tell from your sample, what are your actual columns and types?

Comment: @Andrew Sched_St_Date (TimeStamp(6)), Sched_Time (varchar(255)), Actual_Start (TimeStamp(6)), Actual_End (TimeStamp(6))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert Sched_Time from VARCHAR to TIME.  Then you can normalize Sched_Time to 24-hour format and combine it with Sched_St_Date to get the TIMESTAMP field that you want.

1. Clean up, extract and convert the numeric time portion to a TIME field:

> ```
> CAST(  
>   SUBSTRING(Sched_Time FROM 0 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Sched_Time)) AS TIME  
> ) AS NumericTime
> ```

This assumes that all fields have a " " separator.  You may get errors with the CAST depending on how bad your data is.  Just keep adding logic to handle the different conditions.

2. Determine if the value is AM or PM:

> ```
> CASE
>   WHEN POSITION('AM' IN Sched_Time) > 0 THEN 'AM'  
>   WHEN POSITION('PM' IN Sched_Time) > 0 THEN 'PM'  
>   ELSE 'PM' -- Assume 'PM' if not specified (can change as needed)  
> END AS TimeOfDay
> ```

3. Use the pieces above to normalize NumericTime to 24-hour format:

> ```
> CASE  
>   WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(TRIM(Sched_Time) FROM 0 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > 12 THEN NumericTime -- Already in 24-hour format  
>   ELSE CASE  
>     WHEN TimeOfDay = 'AM' THEN NumericTime -- Already suitable for 24-hour format  
>     ELSE NumericTime + INTERVAL '12' HOUR -- Convert 'PM' time to 24-hour format     
>   END
> END AS MyFinalTime
> ```

4. Follow dnoeth's advice to combine the MyFinalTime field with the Sched_Dt field:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526411/8772888

> ```
> CAST(Sched_St_Date AS DATE) + CAST(MyFinalTime AS INTERVAL HOUR TO
> MINUTE) AS Sched_St_Timestamp
> ```

5. Put it all together:

> ```
> SELECT CAST(
>     SUBSTRING(Sched_Time FROM 0 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Sched_Time)) AS TIME
>   ) AS NumericTime,
>   CASE  
>     WHEN POSITION('AM' IN Sched_Time) > 0 THEN 'AM'  
>     WHEN POSITION('PM' IN Sched_Time) > 0 THEN 'PM'  
>     ELSE 'PM' -- Assume 'PM' if not specified (can change as needed)  
>   END AS TimeOfDay,
>   CASE  
>     WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(TRIM(Sched_Time) FROM 0 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > 12 THEN NumericTime -- Already in 24-hour format  
>     ELSE CASE  
>       WHEN TimeOfDay = 'AM' THEN NumericTime -- Already suitable for 24-hour format  
>       ELSE NumericTime + INTERVAL '12' HOUR -- Convert 'PM' time to 24-hour format  
>     END  
>   END AS MyFinalTime,
>   CAST(Sched_St_Date AS DATE) + CAST(MyFinalTime AS INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE) AS Sched_St_Timestamp
> FROM DB.TBL
> ```

I don't have access to a TD system to check, so there may be some syntax errors.  You probably will need to modify the logic to fit your actual data.  Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: You can simplify it to `CASE
  WHEN Substr(Sched_Time, 7,2) = 'PM'  
   AND Cast(Substr(Sched_Time,1,5) AS TIME(0) Format 'hh:mi') < TIME '12:00:00' 
  THEN Cast(Substr(Sched_Time,1,5) AS TIME(0) Format 'hh:mi') + INTERVAL '12' HOUR  
  ELSE Cast(Substr(Sched_Time,1,5) AS TIME(0) Format 'hh:mi')
END`

Comment: And as the final datatype must be an Interval: `CASE
  WHEN Substr(Sched_Time, 7,2) = 'PM'  
   AND Cast(Substr(Sched_Time,1,5) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE) < INTERVAL '12' HOUR
  THEN Cast(Substr(Sched_Time,1,5) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE) + INTERVAL '12'HOUR 
  ELSE Cast(Substr(Sched_Time,1,5) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE)
END`